# In Nopcommerce Can I Import products but putting categories names instead of Id?

Tags: nopcommerce

When you want to import products, using excel, you have to provide the Id for some fields like product Type..is there a plugin or something else to use the product type name instead of the Id ?

Comment: Yes I tried to replace the id with string and it gives an error

Comment: Try exporting the product list, it should include category names, use that as your template to import.

Answer (score 2):

No. The only way to import is to include ID values. You can find appropriate ID values of enums in source code